# Spring MVC app throws a Whitelist error from browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am just staring with Spring MVC development and trying to work my way through a simple form submission app. Here are my [web form](https://github.com/YADAAB/UdacityReview/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html)  and my [controller](https://github.com/YADAAB/UdacityReview/blob/master/src/main/java/com/udacity/jwdnd/c1/review/AnimalController.java)

The app runs without any error from my IntelliJ but gives whitelist error on the browser. I could not find any missing mapping or errors in the app. Am I missing any annotation here

Error message -

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Jul 19 20:41:10 EDT 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404). No message available

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the web server cannot find the page therefore you are getting a 404.

Your post uri definition is here `th:action="@{'/greeting'}` which means it will make a post call to `/greetings` root url of the deployed site.

If you remove backslash and change it to `th:action="@{'greeting'}`, then it should work.

Comment: Figured my mistake. In html form header, I named greeting wrong and caused this havoc. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: you are welcome Abhi. if the answer is correct you can give a +1 and set as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

More of a typo, changed my html form to

```
<form action="#" th:object="${newgreeting}" method="POST" th:action="@{/greeting}">
```